Guidelines for signal routing near an RFID module array
The task at hand is connecting multiple RFID (13.56 Mhz) antennas in an array.
Each antenna works on its own and access to it is by SPI. Only one antenna is active at a given moment.
The technicals:

Signal Voltage: 5 V
RFID Freq: 13.56 Mhz
SPI Frequency: 100 kHz is OK, 1 Mhz is better.
Antenna: PCB antenna, 60 mm × 35 mm. There is a gap of 3 mm between each antenna.
The antennas and SPI routing are on different PCBs.

What would be the correct way to route the signals under the antennas so they 'absorb' as little of the RF signal as possible? For product design reasons it is not possible to route the signals around the antennas or a far distance (more than 3 mm) below them.
Should the signals be routed between (blue) the antennas (there is a 3 mm gap) or through the center (red) of the antennas?


these aren't just antennas – an antenna doesn't "speak" SPI. What you have there is an IC that comes with a loop; it's a complete communications module, not just an antenna. You will need to refer to the documentation of these modules regarding how they can be placed. And: whether you can place them next to each other, at all. It seems to be pretty likely to me that if you put two loop antennas in the same plne, right next to each other, that they will experience heavy cross-talk (visualize the magnetic field lines!)

Also, this feels a bit strange: why put near-field technology in an array, vs multiplexing multiple loops to one controller? Or build a larger-diameter loop to begin with?

multiplexing multiple loops can be possible but using a single transmitter with different loops and have long lines, in different lengths, from the transmitter to the loop has its own problems. one large loop also has its issues especially when you want to get the tag location on the array while using very small tags.

Have you tried that? As said, I find it unlikely to not fail
